# system call to peek next byte from serial port

Tags: raspbian, c, system-calls, usb-device

have a program that does an `open()` on `/dev/ttyACM0`.

I know how to get bytes available using `ioctl()`, but I want to know what is the next available byte's value, without grabbing it.  (A peek).

Is by using the `recv()` call?  If so, how?    Somehow I have missed this point in my googling.

I was trying to use:

```
FILE* f = fdopen(_fd,"r+");
int byte = getc(f);
ungetc(byte,f);
```

but I get a `resource is temporarily unavailable`, presumably because of the pre-existing `open()` call.

Any suggestions?  thank you.

Comment: does it have to be a system call or could you implement a small put-back buffer in your own application?

Comment: `fdopen()` won't fail because the file has already been `open()`ed -- on the contrary, it needs that! But I can't tell where the error would come, and you didn't show the whole code.

Comment: Guess: IIRC the `stdio` library implements `ungetc` by using an internal buffer in the `FILE` structure. This means you can't unget a character twice. This also won't work when the file is opened twice, because each `FILE` has its own buffer, while they should be shared. So I assume for either reason you get an error. Possible solution: Implement your own wrapper that allows peeking, allowing concurrent access as required. Another possible solution: Open it only once, don't use concurrent access.